# Namespace declaration for extension http://openid.net/sreg/1.0 MUST be signed

Tags: java, openid

I am using openid4java client with clamshell openId server.

MessageExtension ext = authSuccess.getExtension(SRegMessage.OPENID_NS_SREG);

While retrieving the user information, I get an exception mentioning that open id parameters should be signed. "Namespace declaration for extension http://openid.net/sreg/1.0 MUST be signed".

It seems like openId4Java mandates that the parameters be signed. How do I configure clamshell open id server to sign the parameters.

Comment: Did you find out the solution?